# I want to count IF both condition are true Logically count by AND excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, vlookup, google-spreadsheets

I have two Columns both are categorical columns. Like `Age_group` and `Engagement_category`.
And I want to get count no. of each engagement_category in each Age_group.

```
| Engagement_category | Age_group |
|:-------------------:|:---------:|
| Nearly Engaged      | 21-26     |
| Not Engaged         | 31-36     |
| Disengaged          | 36-41     |
| Nearly Engaged      | 21-26     |
| Engaged             | 21-26     |
| Engaged             | 26-31     |
```

And Output as

```
| Age_group | Engaged | Nearly Engaged | Not Engagaged | Disengaged |
|:---------:|:-------:|----------------|---------------|------------|
| 21-26     | 1       |                |               |            |
| 26-31     |         |                |               |            |
| 31-36     |         |                |               |            |
| 36-41     |         |                |               |            |
| 41-46     |         |                |               |            |
| 46-51     |         |                |               |            |
```

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Pivot Table:

- `Age_Group` --> `Rows`
- `Engagement_category` --> `Columns`
- `Engagement_category` --> `Values` *should default to the **Count** option*
- Format and rename to suit

#### Data

[image]

#### Pivot Table Fields setup

[image]

#### Pivot Table

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use COUNTIFS:

`=COUNTIFS($A:$A,E$1,$B:$B,$D2)`

[image]

The key here is the correct use of absolute / relative references.

Comment: I am getting some **ERROR**. It says `Circular dependency detected. To resolve with iterative calculation, see File > Spreadsheet settings.` Thanks! @máté-juhász

Comment: It's working now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MaqsudInamdar accept answer as correct if it works for you

Comment: Though I have `Not Engaged` in `31-36`. I am getting the whole row as zero.                      `=COUNTIFS($A:$A,G$4,$B:$B,$D4)` .

Comment: @MaqsudInamdar probably your data contains leading / trailing spaces, therefore Excel doesn't recognize your values to be the same. Try to remove them