# COUNTIFS value doesn't changing

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have two Columns both are categorical columns. Like Age_group and Engagement_category. And I want to get count no. of each engagement_category in each Age_group.

| Engagement_category | Age_group |
| --- | --- |
| Nearly Engaged | 21-26 |
| Not Engaged | 31-36 |
| Disengaged | 36-41 |
| Nearly Engaged | 21-26 |
| Engaged | 21-26 |
| Engaged | 26-31 |

Required OUTPUT:

| Age_group | Engaged | Nearly Engaged | Not Engagaged | Disengaged |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21-26 | 1 |  |  |  |
| 26-31 |  |  |  |  |
| 31-36 |  |  |  |  |
| 36-41 |  |  |  |  |
| 41-46 |  |  |  |  |
| 46-51 |  |  |  |  |

Thank you for your time and consideration.

I tried :

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,E$1,$B:$B,$D2)
```

This worked fine with the First two category such as `[21-26]` and `[26-31]`. But in the case of `[31-36]` I am getting the whole row as `0`.

Comment: The problem is in your data not the formula. make sure `31-36` is exactly that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to count IF both condition are true Logically count by AND excel](https://superuser.com/questions/1497687/i-want-to-count-if-both-condition-are-true-logically-count-by-and-excel)

Comment: ` I am getting the whole row as 0.` <-- probably there is an extra 'space' in ur data. (happened to me b4..)